Can't retrieve optimal weights for Max Sharpe Ratio in R code
Can someone help me please perform MPT on my portfolio of 6 stocks, specifically to maximize the  SharpeRatio with the following two constraints:

the sum of all weights should be 1,

all the weights should be >=0.05.


I wrote a code in R using the fportfolio package. I get a close sharpe ratio  as I get in Excel with the Solver, but when I try to retrieve the weights for the specific max(SharpeRatio) from an array, I don't get the correct optimal weights corresponding to that SharpeRatio.
Here's my code in R that works and shows me the max of SharpeRatio:
library(quantmod)
library(fPortfolio)

symbols <- c("CRM", "GS", "LLY", "NEE", "NOC", "ORCL")
getSymbols(symbols, from = "2019-09-27", to = "2024-09-29")

prices <- do.call(merge, lapply(symbols, function(x) Ad(get(x))))
log_returns <- na.omit(diff(log(prices)))

getSymbols("^IRX", from = "2019-09-27", to = "2024-09-29")
rf_rates <- na.omit(na.approx(Ad(IRX) / 100 / 360))
rf_rates <- rf_rates[index(log_returns)]

excess_returns <- log_returns - matrix(rf_rates, nrow = nrow(log_returns), ncol = ncol(log_returns), byrow = TRUE)

mean_excess_returns <- colMeans(excess_returns)
cov_matrix_excess   <- cov(excess_returns)

portfolio_data <- portfolioData(data = list(mu = mean_excess_returns, Sigma = cov_matrix_excess))
spec <- portfolioSpec()
setRiskFreeRate(spec) <- mean(rf_rates)
constraints <- c("LongOnly", "minW[1:6]=0.05", "sumW=1")

opt_portfolio <- portfolioFrontier(data = portfolio_data, spec = spec, constraints = constraints)

target_returns <- getTargetReturn(opt_portfolio@portfolio)
target_risks   <- getTargetRisk(opt_portfolio@portfolio)
target_return  <- as.numeric(target_returns)
target_risk    <- as.numeric(target_risks)
sharpe_ratios  <- (target_return - mean(rf_rates)) / target_risk

frontier <- data.frame(Return = target_returns, Risk = target_risks, SharpeRatio = sharpe_ratios)

max_sharpe_index <- which.max(frontier$SharpeRatio)
max_sharpe_ratio <- frontier$SharpeRatio[max_sharpe_index]

cat("Maximum Sharpe Ratio:", max_sharpe_ratio, "\n")`

